# How to update db with phpmyadmin when I add ForeignKey in django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-database

I have django model:

```
#models.py

class m1(models.Model):
    some_word = models.CharField()
```

I've made db with 'manage.py syncdb' command and then added a ForeignKey field to a model

```
#models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class m1(models.Model):
    some_word = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

As far as I know, native django doesn't provide db modifying, so I need to create column 'user_id' manually. Ok, I go to phpmyadmin and create this column. At this moment everything is ok and app works. But then I understand that I need option 'blank = True' at the user field:

```
#models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class m1(models.Model):
    some_word = models.CharField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank = True)
```

And while saving any m1 object, I got error 'Cannot assign None: "m1.user" does not allow null values'. I know that if I delete table and make it with syncdb, everything will be fine, and if I use migrating tool like South, it will be ok too. But I want to understand mechanics of this and find out, what is wrong with db.

I call 'manage.py sqlall app' and it tells 'CREATE TABLE' and create indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX `app_m1_a703c35a` ON `app_m1` (`user_id`);

ALTER TABLE `app_m1` ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_id_5b1b34cc` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);
```

Ok, I go to phpmyadmin and do this sql stuff (frankly, i don't know what these indexes do).
But the error is still occurs. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should use South to do these database migrations for you, especially as you admit you don't really understand what's going on.

Secondly, the error is not because it's missing `blank=True`, but because it's missing `null=True`, which is a completely different thing. The documentation explains this well.